# java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, sqlite, stack-overflow

I get some text from my sqlite database and place it in a variable:

```
opis = c.getString(11);
```

Cursor works fine in the rest of my app.
Now I call another activity with an intent and send it the string:

```
Intent opis = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Popup_opis.class);
opis.putExtra("poslatOpis", opis);
startActivity(opis);
```

In that class I take that string and place it in another one, and then set that text to a TextView. That popup activity works fine when I call it with just word "text" in that TextView. Now, here's that activity:

```
public class Popup_opis extends Activity{

    TextView opis;
    String poslatOpis, primljenOpis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.popup_opis);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           primljenOpis = extras.getString("poslatOpis");
        }

        initVariables();

    }

    private void initVariables() {
        Typeface tv = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARIALN.TTF");
        opis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOpis);
        opis.setTypeface(tv);
        opis.setText(primljenOpis);

    }

}
```

And here's the LogCat:

```
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:484)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5503)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1151)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1070)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
04-03 13:59:54.424: E/AndroidRuntime(28413):    at android.os.Bundle.writeT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmmm use better names for variables ... now all vars have name `opis` (`TextView`, `Intent`, `String` ...) ... with this line `opis.putExtra("poslatOpis", opis);` you put `Intent`(not `String`) to `Intent` as Extra ... and thats why you ended with StackOverflow ...

Comment: If you observe the stack trace,     `writeMapInternal , writeToParcel , writeBundle`  are executing recursively which cause the Stackoverflow Exception, please post your previous activity code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent opis = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Popup_opis.class);
opis.putExtra("poslatOpis", opis);
```

You are putting your `opis`intent inside your intent extras, creating infinite recursion when parceled. Use a different variable name for the intent and `poslatOpis`.

Comment: I didn't see my Intent was named opis also. Damn! I changed Intent opis to Intent i and it works now. One little thing and I just can't see it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the `Intent` and the `String` are named opis. You are probably parceling the Intent. Parcel the string as the extra instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Change
opis = c.getString(11);
// to
opisString = c.getString(11);

// and change
opis.putExtra("poslatOpis", opis);
// to
opis.putExtra("poslatOpis", opisString);
```

Comment: Thank you mate, unfortunate variable naming was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had this stackOverflowError. Problem in my case was that one of the properties of my data class constructor was the Bundle which is a Parcelable as well. It tried to parcel the parcelable and so the recursion.